# What does N.B. stand for?

Tags: acronyms, word-usage

I have received letters for years, and some of the most common things in letters are post-scripts, however, there are also these funny little "N.B." which obviously do not stand for Post Script. What are these letters and how are they used?

Comment: By the way: Post Script is not the right explanation of "P.S.", but is actually **Post Scriptum**. It's _Latin_, not English.

Comment: @Alenanno, Post Script is accepted in English. However, Nota Bene has no translated equivalent using the same abbreviation.

Comment: @Derk-Jan Karrenbeld: Yeah, but I don't like it lol

Comment: If you google for NB/N.B. you get a lot of websites.

Comment: For somebody with such a high rep I find it incredible that this question was allowed to pass through, even if it was posted more than three years ago.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Derived from the Latin (and italian) *nota bene*, meaning **note well** (take notice).
It is used to draw the attention to a certain aspect.

Comment: Here's a few more too: "e.g.":`exempli gratia`: for the sake of example, "i.e.": `id est`: it/that is, "a.d.":`anno domini`: in the year of our lord, "a.m./p.m.":`ante/post meridiem`: before/after midday, "Q.E.D.":`quod erat demonstrandum`: that which was to be demonstrated, "B.I.D.":`bis in die`: twice a day, "etc.":`et cetera`:and the rest,"et al.":`et alii`(pronounced "al ee ee"):and others.  et cetera, et cetera, et cetera.

Answer (score 6):

**Nota Bene** = *note well* in latin, basicially just "note"